# Extended Application can not run correctly

Tags: android, android-application-class

everyone. I am new to android. 
Recently, I tried to learn how to extend Application, but there is
a strange problem. I have tried a lot of methods, but still can not
solve it. So, thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

The code section is like this:

package com.example.xw.myfirstapplication;

```
import android.app.Application;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 2016/8/26.
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static MyApplication mApplication;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    mApplication = this;

    }

    public static MyApplication getMyApplication(){
        return mApplication;
    }
}
```

And, Manifest.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xw.myfirstapplication"
    >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:name="com.example.xw.myfirstapplication.MyApplication"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>-->
        <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>-->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--<activity android:name="testNewTech.DisplayMessageActivity" />
        <activity android:name="testNewTech.NotificationActivity"></activity>-->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But, when I run the code, something happens very quickly, like this:

[image]

In addition: 
1. I tried not to use extended Application but default Application, everything     is good.

2. I add  **Log.v("MainActivity", "start onCreate");** in method **onCreate()** of class **MainActivity**. But, there is nothing in logcat, so I think the method **onCreate()** of class **MainActivity** is not processed.

So, anyone has any advice? Thank you so much!

Comment: please share your log.

Comment: There is no log. Completely empty.

Comment: There's a stacktrace/log if your app crashes. Post that.

Comment: Follow this link will help you.  http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: you just put your log before onCreate() method and check it, Is it printed or not ? and what is your Application class?

Comment: If you haven't managed to solve the problem yet, maybe you could give us enough code to reproduce it? It's much easier to work with a small sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see in your manifest.xml file then you can pass another class

```
<application android:name="com.example.xw.myfirstapplication.MyApplication"
...
...
>
```

just change

```
<application android:name="com.example.xw.myfirstapplication.Application"
...
...
>
```